# How do I prevent ListBox - Multiselect Change Event from firing twice on the first selection?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a `UserForm` that has two `ListBoxes`, one populated from a `dictionary` that contains excess items from a company report, and the other from a `dictionary` that contains excess items from a bank report. The first `ListBox` is a `fmMultiSelectMulti`, allowing the user to select multiple items to get the sum of the selected items (which change the value of a `TextBox`).

My issue is when I select the first item in the `ListBox`, the `ListBox_Change()` event fires twice. The sum variable is public since it is referenced in other methods, but upon the double-fire, it doubles the real value.

Here's the code for the change event:

```
Private Sub GPListBox_Change()

    For lItem = 0 To GPListBox.ListCount - 1
        If GPListBox.Selected(lItem) = True Then
            gpTotal = gpTotal + GPListBox.List(lItem, 1)
            Debug.Print GPListBox.List(lItem, 1)
        End If
    Next

    GPTotalTextBox.Value = Format(gpTotal, "$#,##0.00")

End Sub
```

The other method that removes the (multiple) selected variables, and references the sum variable:

```
Private Sub RemoveButton1_Click()

    For lItem = GPListBox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If GPListBox.Selected(lItem) Then
            gpTotal = gpTotal - GPListBox.List(lItem, 1)
            'GPListBox.RemoveItem GPListBox.ListIndex
            GPListBox.RemoveItem lItem
            GPTotalTextBox.Value = gpTotal
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

This is the UserForm after I selected the first item, which automatically deselected and left the sum present:

[image]
.

**My Question:** How do I prevent this from double-firing every time the first selection occurs?

Comment: Set a Boolean to `true` the first time the event is fired and only allow it to fire when the `Boolean = false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got around it like this in the past.  Something like this.

Use a global boolean at the top of you code. Above all subs and functions.

```
Dim bFire as Boolean
```

A boolean is false by default so you will have to set the boolean to true somewhere outside of you subs such as form `UserForm_Initialize` event or something.  If you don't have a place to do that, switch the true/false usage in the subs (Benno Grimm Elaborated on this below in comments).

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    bFire = True
End Sub
```

Then use the boolean in the subs.

```
Private Sub GPListBox_Change()
    'Check the status and get out if you have set it to not fire.
    If bFire = false then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For lItem = 0 To GPListBox.ListCount - 1
        If GPListBox.Selected(lItem) = True Then
            gpTotal = gpTotal + GPListBox.List(lItem, 1)
            Debug.Print GPListBox.List(lItem, 1)
        End If
    Next

    GPTotalTextBox.Value = Format(gpTotal, "$#,##0.00")

End Sub
```

In the button that modifies it, set the boolean false at the start and true at the end.

```
Private Sub RemoveButton1_Click()

    'Set it false
    bFire = false

    For lItem = GPListBox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If GPListBox.Selected(lItem) Then
            gpTotal = gpTotal - GPListBox.List(lItem, 1)
            'GPListBox.RemoveItem GPListBox.ListIndex
            GPListBox.RemoveItem lItem
            GPTotalTextBox.Value = gpTotal
        End If
    Next

    'After you have modified the control set it to true
    bFire = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Just turn it around, `RemoveButton1_Click()` -> `bFire = true` & `GPListBox_Change()` -> `If bFire = true Then...` Then you don't need the `UserFrom_Initialize()` part.